# print a diamond of numbers in python

Tags: python

```
      1
     121
    12321
   1234321
  123454321
   1234321
    12321
     121
      1
```

I can only print stars but have no logic for numbers.

```
userInput = int(input("Please input side length of diamond: "))

if userInput > 0:
    for i in range(userInput):
        for s in range(userInput -3, -2, -1):
            print(" ", end="")
        for j in range(i * 2 -1):
            print("*", end="")
        print()
    for i in range(userInput, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i * 2 -1):
            print("*", end="")
        print()
```

Comment: format your code please, is not readable like that

Comment: @PM2Ring Maybe the OP meant "**star**s" (asterisks)

Comment: @iBug Probably, but I'd like the OP to confirm that.

Comment: @PM2Ring Instead of simply rejecting the edit, you should have rejected/improved it, or provided a more clear reject reason, like: Changing starts to stars may change the question. OP should provide this edit.

Comment: @FrankerZ Yes, I should have. I rejected it because I mistakenly thought that pault had provided indentation that was originally absent; somehow I was looking at the "side-by-side" view instead of the "side-by-side markdown" view. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following can do this concisely using a helper function:

```
def up_and_down(n):  # 1,2, ..., n, ..., 2, 1
    return (*range(1, n), *range(n, 0, -1))

def diamond(n):
    for i in up_and_down(n):
        print((n-i)*' ', *up_and_down(i), sep='') 
       
>>> diamond(5)
    1    
   121   
  12321  
 1234321 
123454321
 1234321 
  12321  
   121   
    1
```

Comment: Prints unnecessary extra spaces at the end of the lines, though. Alternative idea for `up_and_down`: `return (*range(1, n), *range(n, 0, -1))`

Comment: Good idea to use `.center`. But I suspect that this is an exercise in learning how to use `for` loops, so `chain` and `map` might be a bit too advanced at this stage of the OP's learning.

Comment: @StefanPochmann You are right about the spaces, but I will leave it as is for simplicity. The alternative `up_and_down` would require qualification wrt to the Python version and would build an unnecessary tuple.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Ok, but I think `n` and `n` is definitely nicer than `n+1` and `n-1` :-P

Comment: @PM2Ring Probably true. I remember having to do these things in bloody java, and I still have callouses on my finger tips from typing them loops ;)

Answer (score 0):

for i in range (1,6):

```
for j in range(6-i):
    print(" ", end=" ")

for k in range(1,i):
    print(k, end = " ")

for l in range(i, 0, -1):
    print(l, end= " ")


print()
```

for i in range (4,0,-1):
for j in range(6-i):
print(" ", end=" ")

```
for k in range(1,i):
    print(k, end = " ")

for l in range(i, 0, -1):
    print(l, end= " ")
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (very simple) way to handle this is to take advantage of:

1. The call stack.
2. The mathematical property of elevens where: n = a^2.

For example:

- 1 = 1^2
- 121 = 11^2
- 12321 = 111^2
- 1234321 = 1111^2
- etc ...

#### Example Function:

```
def diamond(n, c=1):
    """Print a diamond pattern of (n) lines.

    Args:
        n (int): Number of lines to print.

    """
    string = f'{int("1"*c)**2:^{n}}'
    if c < (n//2)+1:
        print(string)
        diamond(n=n, c=c+1)
    if c <= n:
        print(string)

>>> diamond(7)
```

#### Output:

```
   1   
  121  
 12321 
1234321
 12321 
  121  
   1
```

#### Implementation Note:

There are different ideas as to whether `n` applies to the number of lines printed, or the center value of the diamond. This example implements the former; but is easily modified to implement the latter.