# Anyone knows an easy way to code this problem?

Tags: python, loops

> Write a Python program that prints a diamond made with asterisks where the diamond's height (number of rows) is determined by the value of the variable height
> You can (optionally) ask the user to enter the value of height.
>
> This value can only have an odd number of rows, so you should print a descriptive message if the user enters an even value.

This is what I have, but I don't understand this... Anyone know an easier way to solve this task?

```
import math as m

height = int(input("Enter height - odd number: "))

if ((height > 2) and (height % 2 == 1)):
    
    a = list(range(1, m.floor(height/2) + 1))
    a.append(m.ceil(height/2))
    a = a + list(reversed(list(range(1, m.floor(height/2) + 1))))
    
    for h in a:
        repeat = 2*h-1
        ast = "*"*repeat
        blank = int((height - repeat) /2)
        blk = " "*blank
        print(str(blk) + str(ast) + str(blk))
        
else:
    print("The height must be a positve odd value")
```

Comment: Perhaps [this (similar) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390104/6340496) will help or offer some pointers.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions. [diamond-problem] is about an OOP multiple inheritance issue and is not a tag about drawing diamonds.

Comment: Stackoverflow is to help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Comment: Hi - did you write this code yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the decreasing, then increasing number of spaces with an increasing, then decreasing number of stars:

```
height = 7

for i in range(1-height,height,2):
    print(abs(i)//2*" " + "*"*(height-abs(i)))

   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

The progression of i from `range(1-height,height,2)` will be:

```
-6 -4 -2 0 2 4 6
```

which decreases and then increases if you take i's absolute value `abs(i)`:

```
6 4 2 0 2 4 6
```

This range progression can be converted to the number of spaces and stars for each line:

```
spaces: abs(i)//2     = 3 2 1 0 1 2 3
stars:  height-abs(i) = 1 3 5 7 5 3 1
```

vertically:

```
spaces  stars  |  result (underlines are spaces)
  3       1    |  ___*
  2       3    |  __***
  1       5    |  _*****
  0       7    |  *******
  1       5    |  _*****
  2       3    |  __***
  3       1    |  ___*
```

With these numbers you can multiply the corresponding characters and get the repeated strings that you need for the pattern.

*Note that it also works for even numbers, although the shape is not as pointy on the left and right sides*

The loop can be converted to a comprehension in a one-liner if you want:

```
h = 7

print(*(i//2*' '+(h-i)*'*' for i in map(abs,range(1-h,h,2))),sep='\n')
```

or

```
for i in map(abs,range(1-h,h,2)):print(i//2*' '+(h-i)*'*')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `increasing` and `decreasing` iterators. They tell you how many asterisks to print per row (except for the middle row).

You can easily center the asterisks with the `str.center` method. It's also possible to center it with a format specifier, but I find the latter less readable.

```py
size = int(input("Enter the size of the diamond: "))
if size%2 == 0:
    raise ValueError("The size must be an odd value")

increasing = range(1, size, 2)
decreasing = reversed(increasing)

for i in increasing:
    print(("*" * i).center(size))
print("*" * size)
for i in decreasing:
    print(("*" * i).center(size))
```