# Spacing of two printed shapes side by side individually

Tags: python, loops

So I have to print dual diamonds side by side with the user input as half of the rows in the diamond. However, my middle rows of both diamonds are touching each other. There needs to be a space between both shapes so theyre two unconnected diamonds, and Im unsure of how to do it without botching the whole code up.

```
rows = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows in half of the diamond:"))

#upper triangles 1 and 2
for i in range(rows):
    #spaces for triangle 1
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print(" ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
    #spaces for triangle 2
    for s in range (rows - i) :
        print("  ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
    print()

#lower triangles 3 and 4
for i in range(rows,0,-1):
    #spaces for triangle 3
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print(" ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
    #spaces for triangle 4
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print("  ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
    print()
 

if rows<=0:
    print("Invalid.")
```

Comment: “Im not sure how to code it...”.  Sure, but what is the exact question?  Sounds like a possible variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390104/6340496).

Comment: Yes I have my code for the first diamond, I just need another one by its side.

Comment: You might want to consider storing your diamond objects internally, then printing them all at once.  Say, as a list of string, or some such.  Once stuff is printed to the screen it's a lot of work to go back and modify it.

Comment: I havent used lists yet so Im not really sure

Comment: You could use string just, prolly: `row1 = (" "*5 + "x" + " "*5)*n_diamonds`

Comment: @mkrieger1 `:%s/^>//g`

Answer (score 0):

Think of the output as being on checkerboard paper. Each character is either a space or an asterisk. The printing process is either "this is a gap" or "this is a diamond".

The following arrangement is desired:
`gap` + `stars` + `gap` + `gap` + `stars`

You currently have:
`gap` + `asterisks`

All you need to do is to paste the for loops you already have for the "first diamond" so that they repeat themselves. There is obviously a much cleaner solution to this but this is how it looks while retaining your original code:

```
rows = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows in half of the diamond:"))

#upper triangles
for i in range(rows):
    #gap
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print(" ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
    #gap (notice there are double spaces)
    for s in range (rows - i) :
        print("  ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
    print()

#lower triangles
for i in range(rows,0,-1):
    #gap
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print(" ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
    #gap (notice there are double spaces again)
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print("  ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for maintaining this in my code. Both of the diamonds need to be closed off from each other. Is there a way to make there be a space between them?