# triangle and inverted triangle pyramid implementation

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nested-loops

i am trying to print triangle and an inverted triangle pattern, there is a small error in the logic of the inverted triangle which i am not able to figure out

[image]

I took multiple loops to print spaces, and then stars to print a triangle, I followed the same for inverted by count spaces and then printing stars.

[image]

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(10,15-i):
        print(" ",end=" ")
        
    for z in range(10,2*i+9):
        print("*",end=" ")
    print()

for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(10,i+10):
        print(" ",end=" ")

    for k in range(10,21-2*i):
        print("*",end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390104/6340496) to a similar diamond problem; only substitutes sequential numbers for the asterisks.  In this case, recursion is used as this prints the top half, then ‘unwinds’ the call stack to print the bottom half.

Answer (score 1):

See the comment added by `S3DEV` for a nifty way to do what you want.

However, to align your diamond correctly you need to change the ending range in your second `J` loop to `i+9` rather than `i+10`. Then it will not add the space you're seeing at the front of the line.

### Alternatively:

Using only one loop and some string manipulation you can achieve the same thing and save some lines/loops.

```
n = 5 #the number of rows in your triangle
w = (n*2)-1 #the width of your rows
```

Now build your triangle by centre aligning lines of asterisks, joining them together with newlines.

```
t = '\n'.join([f'{"*"*i}'.center(w, ' ') for i in range(1, w+2, 2)])
```

### Output:

```
print(t)
    *    
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Then instead of creating the bottom half of your diamond from scratch, you can just reverse your triangle and join it to the original one.

```
d =  '\n'.join([t, t[::-1]])
```

### Output:

```
print(d)
    *    
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

Comment: I like the way you’ve created the bottom half. Nicely done.